# Can't get my slideshow to work through my database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

For some reason it displays the first image but wont slide onto the next images. Image sources should be fine, but once i added in php tags for my images the slider functionality stoppe

Script in head tags:

```
var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
slideimages[0].src = "<?php echo "<img src='images/$firstslider'/>";?>" 
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "<?php echo "<img src='images/$secondslider'/>";?>"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "<?php echo "<img src='images/$thirdslider'/>";?>"
```

Code for slider in body:

```
<div id="slider">
<a href="#" id="slide" width="910px" height="250px"><?php echo "<img src='images/$firstslider'   />";?></a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var step = 0

    function slideit() {

        if (!document . images)
            return
            document.getElementById ('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
        if (step < 2)
            step++
        else
        step = 0

        setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
    }

    slideit()

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign an image element to a image source attribute

use this instead:

```
slideimages[0].src = "<?= "images/$firstslider" ?>"
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you hit f12 on your browser and take a look at the console and see if you've got any javascript errors, it might give you a clue where the problem is